# How is XP shared between multiple teammates attacking the same wild Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-unite

Alt title: Does Pokemon Unite have a Last Hit mechanic?

When me and my teammate head up the lane and start farming xp, how is xp shared between us? Is it based on our overall contribution to the kill, or is it based on who gets the last hit, like in some other mobas?

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, it has a last hit mechanic.

From my testing (I'm a master ranked player), all participants who attack wild Pokemon/other players gain about half of the experience that last hits give (when the damage occurs in a timeframe, I have not tested the exact timeframe). This includes gaining experience from wild Pokemon that the other team kills (except for objective experience).

So everyone who damages a wild Pokemon will get a share of the exp, and the last hit gives additional exp.

Comment: Not to mention, the last hit also gives you the points of the wild Pokemon.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, there is a last hit mechanic.**

- If there's only one player, they get 100% of the experience.
- If there are several players, the last-hitter will get 70% of the experience, and every other player will get 30%.
- If there are several players and one of the players has an EXP share, then the last-hitter will get 100% of the experience, and every other player will get 30%.